# Angular2 Form variable does not work without ngModel

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have the html below:

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <input type="text" name="dd" value="abc" (change)="foof(f.form.value)"/>
</form>
```

However, the f.form.value has nothing in it when foof function is called when I change the input text value.
Only if I add ngModel to the input element like below,

```
 <input type="text" name="dd" [ngModel]="abc" (change)="foof(f.form.value)"/>
```

Then f.form.value has the dd input text value.
I don't understand why is this. Do I have to use ngModel to get the form variable to work right?

Note: For certain reasons in our app, we have to submit the whole form when the dd input is changed, so I do need foof(f.form.value). I also don't want two way binding, just one way binding due to variations between the model and the html layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could make a hack like this:

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <input type="text" id="someInput" value="abc" (change)="foof()"/>
</form>
```

and

```
x:any;

foof() {
    this.x = document.getElementById("someInput");
    console.log(this.x.value);
}
```

Don't know your app, so this (terrible) hack might not at all suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks!! This solved this problem and simultaneously solved another problem for me where I have to have a form spread across multiple components and was not using reactive forms but template driven forms. Using javascript made that possible too!

Comment: Great! Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is how you're supposed to be binding to an input field.

You should be doing it like this,

```
 <input type="text" name="dd" [(ngModel)]="abc" (ngModelChange)="foof(abc)"/>
```

Comment: For certain reasons in our app, we have to submit the whole form when the dd input is changed, so I do need foof(f.form.value). I also don't want two way binding, just one way binding due to variations between the model and the html layout.